# How to compare part of String element of a matrix to another String in R?

Tags: r, string, matrix, escaping

I have a matrix with String elements. I put a name to each column and row of this matrix. So I can call the elements of a column by:

```
    > mymatrix[,"mycolumnname1"]
    myrowname1
     "mystringA"
    myrowname2
     "mystringB"
    myrowname2
     "otherstringA"
```

Now I want to compare each elements but only part of the string, for example to "mystring". If I do the following, I will get all FALSE result:

```
    > mymatrix[,"mycolumnname1"] == "mystring*"
    myrowname1
         FALSE
    myrowname2
         FALSE
    myrowname2
         FALSE
```

Can anyone help me so I will get result:

```
    myrowname1
          TRUE
    myrowname2
          TRUE
    myrowname2
         FALSE
```

because the string elements in row 1 and 2 contain the string "mystring".

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grepl("mystring",myMatrix[,"mycolumnname1"])` should return the result you want. `grepl` also takes an `ignore.case` argument that you can set to `TRUE` or `FALSE` as you require.